# Downloading in Chrome on Ubuntu 18.04. doesn't work sometimes. Stuck in Filebrowser

Tags: 18.04, nautilus, google-chrome

Sometimes when i want to download random files with the Google Chrome Browser, the file browser won't work.

It will open and show the suggested filename, but now folder is selected (no path shown, no item selected) and neither any content.

- "Save" is not clickable.
- The Mouse Cursor has the loading circle.
- Clicking on the Folders won't change anything
- Some mounted folders are not listed
- Only Clicking on "Other Locations" show other locations. But a Click to some location will result in an empty folder view again.

I assume in the background a folder is selected, because the filename changes to "XXX(1)" if a file with the same name "XXX" is already there.

I can close the window and work normally. But every further download has the same problem.
I can click on the "New Folder"-Icon and all Google Chrome Tabs will freeze, when i try to enter a name (this is now my favorite way to reset).
After Freezing and Force Quit or after a system reboot it will work again.

Does someone have the same problem or suggestions?